# QGIS: Atlas of child layer (points) but use geometry of parent layer (polygon) to create map

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

We are creating an atlas using point features (centroids from a polygon parent layer) to iterate through. But in the atlas map we need to display the related parent polygons. In QGIS one-to-many-relationship is set for the parent-child layers using an uuid field.

Is there a way to use the geometry of the parent layer (polygons) in the 'controlled by atlas' section to define margins around the parent polygons so that they are displayed entirely?

Comment: You could set a scale that works for each page in the point feature attribute table and use that in your Atlas settings.  see bottom answer in this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416699/setting-atlas-scale-and-scale-bar-for-each-map-to-round-number-using-qgis  To make it easier you might go through your points and find that three different scales will work well enough and then select and calculate that value into multiple rows of the attribute table.

Comment: Ok, as workaround, this would be ok, but I don't want to add a new field to the child layer. I could use a PostgreQSL-view, that fetches the geometry of the parent layer instead. But I need to need to keep original child layer. I was wondering if it would be possible to access the parent layer using a function based on the @atlas_feature since both layers are linked trough an one-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an atlas based on a polygon coverage layer, go to `Item Properties` and expand `Controlled by Atlas`: there, you can set the `Margin around feature` in percents, see screenshot:

[image]